# How to run an initializer method in Java when JVM starts?

Tags: java, maven, jvm

I am building a Java library of a few Java, Maven projects. There is no main method in any of the projects since it is a library. In web applications, you can create a class that implements ServletContextListener and it will execute when your server starts (e.g. when Tomcat starts). I want to do the same, but for the library (which is not a web application or a console application. It is just a reusable library). If someone writes a program that uses my library, I want my initialzer class to execute when the JVM starts in order to do some initialization I want it to do. How could I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Normally you simply add your library to any java project and import the class you are willing to use. If you want your initializer class to execute then call it in the main method of your other java program.

Comment: Is it *absolutely necessary* for you initializer to run when the JVM starts, or does it just have to run before any of the library code is used? The first cannot be done without adding code to the main code using the library. The second is common and is called [*lazy initialization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization), i.e. the initialization is deferred until needed.

Comment: What sort of initialization? Depending on what it is, it might be possible to just put `static` blocks in the classes that rely on said initialization. Or it might be necessary to communicate to future users, via the documentation, that some pre-configuration is necessary before using the library. It really depends on what sort of initialization we're talking about.

Comment: This sort of sounds like an X-Y problem and also something a library shouldn't perhaps be doing.

Comment: Tell the users of your library to call method X to initialize it.

Comment: You're asking a very generic question for what appears to be a very specific issue. Instead of abstracting your issue away into something generic, describe exactly what you're trying to achieve: the ends, and not the means (with the "library initialising automatically" being the means).

Comment: @Andreas, it is the 2nd. Execute some code that loads a prop file before any other class is used

Comment: @SeverityOne, I want to use the initialisation code so that I can register a few properties from prop files to the configuration registry at the very beginning, right before the JVM finishes its startup/initialisation, i.e. before anyone makes a call to the library

Comment: @DimitriosEfthymiou Then look at the link I gave earlier, or search the web for *lazy initialization*. If you need your configuration registry to be initialized from property file before it is used, it should probably be the registry that auto-initializes itself lazily when first accessed, e.g. in a `static` initializer block.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a JAR as a `-javaagent:` on the command line, a `premain` method will be called *before* the main of the program you are running.

e.g.

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class Agent {
  public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation instrumentation){
    // early initalization
  }
}
```

https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-inspect-classes-in-your-jvm/

Answer (score 1):

I guess the question boils down to how you can initialise your objects before they’re used. This, in turn, depends on what data you need to perform your initialisation. If you need:

- to perform initialisation work that is not dependent on outside information, then you can do this at object creation (eg in a constructor or, if you’re using an EE framework, in something like a @PostConstruct annotated method), or in a static initialisation block that will be run at class loading time.
- data from your user’s environment, static calls in the [System](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) class can provide this. Again, this can be done at object construction time.
- static choices users have made about how to use your library, consider using a property file (which will need to be documented). Again, object construction is the time to do this.
- dynamic choices users have made about using your library, this will be available at runtime somewhere within the objects collaborating with your library.

If your initialisation work is resource intensive and you want to do it when your user’s app starts, then I think the best way to achieve this is to document the requirement and ask users to call specific methods that will perform the initialisation.

From a library user perspective, I want to know when your library does initialisation work and how heavy that work is. I don’t want a library making decisions about when it will consume resources, particularly at startup when I might have lots of my own startup code, framework code and countless other bits of initialisation all contributing to startup lag.

**Edit**: Just to be clear, all of these options are at the application level. The JVM itself is already up and running. We’re talking about initialisation of application code and not the JVM.

Comment: I am not using Spring Beans. A static block would be perfect, but unfortunately it executes when someone uses the class for the first time (lazy-init) and not when the classloader is working at the JVM startup. I want to use the initialisation code so that I can register a few properties from prop files to the configuration registry at the very beginning, right before the JVM finishes its startup/initialisation, i.e. before anyone makes a call to teh library. So, the question is how can I register the props from the prop files (that exist in src/main/resources) when the JVM starts?

Comment: Static block will initialise at class load time and not when a user first accesses a class method, so this might be a good option. Other than that, if you’re asking a user to edit a property file then it makes sense (to me) to also ask them to call an initialisation method in order to use your library.

Comment: I still don't get the "right before the JVM finishes its startup/initialisation" bit. It is not possible to invoke a method a method, static or not, on a class, without the `static` block being executed first. You're focussing on the exact point of execution and it just doesn't make sense, to me at least.

Answer (score 1):

You want specific initialization code always to be executed at first, before a (Java) library is being used.

The J2EE/Spring option using `@PostConstruct` has already been addressed for the question posed. Using Java SE, you can encapsulate your Java library by a **singleton** class - a class which is the 'entrance' to the rest of the functionality of your library.

The constructor of the singleton class can call all necessary initialization code, before passing control back to the caller (the main web-application).

```
public class LibraryInstance {

    private FunctionalClass1 functionalClass1;
    private FunctionalClass2 functionalClass2;
    ...

    private LibraryInstance() { runInitializingCode(); }
    private static final LibraryInstance instance = new LibraryInstance();
    public static LibraryInstance getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private void runInitializingCode() { 
        ....
    }
}
```

Should work out-of-the-box.

Comment: so, essentially you are suggesting I should create an API gateway or a facade for each project. I want to use the initialisation code so that I can register properties from prop files to the configuration registry at the very beginning, right before the JVM finishes its startup/initialisation. So, the question is how can I register the props from the prop files (that exist in src/main/resources) when the JVM starts?

Comment: You can add a @PostConstruct-annotated method to your main web-application. That method can read the properties you mention and subsequently call LibraryInstance (possibly passing the relevant subset of parameters - not shown in my code example above), in order to instantiate the library during JVM-startup.